# removing results from Google searches on Safari

Tags: macos, safari, google

Is there any extension or whatever that I can use to remove the results I don't want form google for safari?

I would like to be able to ban certain domains from appearing in any results on my google searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will go ahead and make a global answer:

- [**Extension for Safari**](https://github.com/nubilus/Personal-Search-Result-Blocker)
- [Extension for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef)
- [Extension for Mozilla Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/hide-unwanted-results-of-go/)